# Getting the last 5 days date from input (read command line)

Tags: date

I have a script that will get the last 5 days from the data input by the user.

Example:

```
Choose the month: 
1 - Jan
2 - Feb
...
12- Dec  // I used if else here 

Insert day:
30
```

My expected output would be this:

```
Jun 30
Jun 29
Jun 28
Jun 27
Jun 26
```

Is this possible? I already check `date` command but I can only replicate getting the date today then use `-d` command.  I can't input the date I want to check.

Comment: Side note: You might want to take a look into the `CASE` selector instead of using an `IF` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `date(1)`:

```
start_day=3
start_month=Jun
for d in {0..4}; do
    date -d "$start_month $start_day - $d days" +'%b %d'
done
```

Output:

```
Jun 03
Jun 02
Jun 01
May 31
May 30
```

Doing the same without GNU `date(1)` is possible, but potentially a lot more painful.

Comment: okay let me try this.

Comment: I just replace the  `date -d "$start_month $start_day - $d days" +'%b %d'` to  `date -d "$start_month $start_day - $d days" +'%b %_d'` to have space on the non-double digit.